# How to store values from a dynamic sql into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to store next value for the sequence into a variable and the statement is called in a dynamic sql as below.

```
DECLARE @Sequence VARCHAR(100) = 'IMEIIDLookUP'
DECLARE @NextVal INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@Sequence) + ')'

SELECT  @NextVal = EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT @NextVal
```

The above query fails with error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

What would be the correct syntax here? Having said that, I cannot avoid using dynamic sql.

Comment: read about sp_execute. It allows passing parameters back and forth

Comment: nope, it threw the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @Sequence VARCHAR(100) = 'IMEIIDLookUP';
DECLARE @NextVal INT;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT @NextVal = (NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@Sequence) + ')';

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@NextVal int output', @NextVal = @NextVal output;

SELECT @NextVal;
```